# Dynamic path variable to play audio .mp3 file How to ? d3 javascript coffe script

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, audio, d3.js

I am trying to play a sound file on "mouseover". It works when I hardcode the path to the .mp3 file, code shown below.

My values, including the paths to multiple .mp3 files, are stored in a .csv file, though.
And I need to find a way to 'feed' the path values to a variable.

Here is my initial element. There are multiple nodes, taking the values from .csv parsing. On mouse over, I can play the - "hardcoded path" - .mp3 file ok:

> ```
> labelEnter.append("span")
>   .attr("class", "bubble-sound")
>   .attr("height", 40 )
>   .attr("width", 70 )
>   .attr("src",(d) -> "sounds/"+fileValue(d))
>   .on("mouseover",  (d, i) -> playSound d.file)
>
> playSound = (d) ->
>     # hardcoded here in next line
>   snd.setAttribute "src", "sounds/Hungarian_FSI_1_0.00.06.059-0.00.07.229.mp3"
>   snd.load()
>   snd.play()
>   return
>
> snd = new Audio()
>
> onPlay = (e) ->
>   snd = new Audio()
>   snd.addEventListener "play", onPlay
> ```

I am trying to get the path-value parsed from the .csv into the snd.setAttribute statement, that is, replace the hard-coded path with a variable, that holds the path value for that node.
The following code shows the correct value of 'file' in the console.log, but it displays undefined for the "setAttribute" path

> ```
> playSound = (d) ->
>   file = fileValue(d)
>       # console log shows desired value of 'file'
>   console.log("Show me " + file)
>       # 'file' undefined
>   snd.setAttribute "src", "sounds/"+file
>   snd.load()
>   snd.play()
>    on "mouseoverreturn
> ```

My question, beginner, how can I manipulate/set the file variable so that it would correctly append to the source path: "sounds/file-value-as-string-here" in the setAttribute statement ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try `setAttribute("src", "sounds/"+file);`?  (added parenthesis)

Comment: GET http://localhost/~ediestel/test1/sounds/undefined 
    Show me Hungarian_FSI_1_0.00.06.059-0.00.07.229.mp3               - this  is the console response with brackets

Comment: Ok, found the first mistake -> the '+' in the setAttribute relates to numerical values, has to be removed for a string.

Comment: It is a syntax issue:                               snd.setAttribute("src", "#{file}")    - this line works if I leave the hardcoded prefix "sounds/" away. I didn't find the correct way to write this line yet. The .mp3 files have to stay in the main directory for now. If anybody know how to write this, please let me know.

Comment: The console.log statement shows the right string?  The `+` sign is the correct concatenate operator in javaScript, so `"sounds/"+file` will give you the correct string.  Try `console.log("Show me '" + "sounds/"+file+"'");` (I put ticks in to make sure there's no unwanted space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
playSound = (d) ->
  file = fileValue(d)
      # console log shows desired value of 'file'
  console.log("Show me " + file)
      # 'file' undefined
  snd.setAttribute("src", "sounds/"+file); //<-- this line changed
  snd.load()
  snd.play()
```

Comment: I think with more credits I have more options. I accepted your answer. The code that I am using is found below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank your responding; this is my final solution:

```
playSound = (d) ->
    file = fileValue(d)
    console.log("Show me " + file)
    snd.setAttribute("src", "#{file}")
    snd.load()
    snd.play()
    return

  snd = new Audio()

  onPlay = (e) ->
    snd = new Audio()
    snd.addEventListener "play", onPlay
```